# In SVD, what is the difference between the right singular vectors and the left ones?

Tags: linear-algebra

For the decomposition $A = U\Sigma V^T$, U contains the left singular vectors and V contains the right singular vectors.

What is the difference between them? What do each of them intuitively represent?

Also, what's the difference between $U\ \Sigma$ and $ \Sigma V^T$?